# Error when trying to serialize multiple followers:Got AttributeError when attempting to get a value for field `email` on serializer `UserSerializer`

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I am trying to show the followers in UserSerializer,as a user instance.Almost the same method i used in article model works,but in user model it gives me problem.Below i can explain it better with my codes:
**Models.py**

```
class User(AbstractUser,PermissionsMixin):

    id = models.UUIDField(primary_key=True, default=uuid.uuid4, editable=False)
    email = models.CharField(max_length=255,unique=True)
    username =models.CharField(max_length=80,unique=True,default='SOME STRING')

class Article(models.Model):

    id = models.UUIDField(primary_key=True, default=uuid.uuid4, editable=False)
    author = models.ForeignKey(User,on_delete=models.CASCADE,related_name='articles')
    caption = models.CharField(max_length=250)

class FollowUserModel(models.Model):

    id = models.UUIDField(primary_key=True, default=uuid.uuid4, editable=False)
    author = models.ForeignKey(User,on_delete=models.CASCADE,related_name='followers')
    profile = models.ForeignKey(User,on_delete=models.CASCADE,null=True)
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
```

**Serializers.py**

```
class UserSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    followers_set = serializers.SerializerMethodField()

    def get_followers_set(self, user):
        return UserSerializer(user.followers.all(), source='followers', required=False,read_only=True,many=True).data

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields  = ('id','email','username','followers_set')

class ArticleViewSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    author = UserSerializer(required=False,read_only=True)

    class Meta:
        model = Article
        fields = ('id','author')


    def create(self, validated_data):
     return Article.objects.create(**validated_data)


class FollowSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    author = UserSerializer(required=False)
    profile = UserSerializer(required=False)

    class Meta:
        model = FollowUserModel
        fields = ("author","profile")
```

Now the author works as intended,it gives the full user instance.But in followers_set i get this error:

`` Got AttributeError when attempting to get a value for field `email` on serializer `UserSerializer`. The serializer field might be named incorrectly and not match any attribute or key on the `FollowUserModel` instance. Original exception text was: 'FollowUserModel' object has no attribute 'email'. ``
I don't get it,like i defined everything accordingly but i still get this error.

Does anybody know the reason?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
User.followers.all()
```

is a queryset of **FollowUserModel**, not **User** model. So when you run that query, you get FollowUserModel instances, and when you pass that queryset to  **UserSerializer**, as it expects **User** model instances get get their emails, this exception is raised. You can update **get_followers_set** method like this:

```
def get_followers_set(self, user):
    return UserSerializer(User.objects.filter(followusermodel__author=user), many=True).data
```

to get a queryset of User instances.